# Does changing username affect progress?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm scared that when I change my MC username, all my progress and servers will be lost.

Is this what will happen?

Answer (score 6):

No, you won't. Players are tracked with a unique ID, instead of your username as of Minecraft 1.7.10. You can only change your username every 30 days, and if someone changes their username, you cannot change it to their username for 37 days.
As for servers, you'll have to ask the server owner, but you *usually* don't lose progress.
https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames

Comment: Appending this, single players worlds will stay because they are saved in a file in the Minecraft folder, and that doesn't change with your account.

Comment: Vanilla server should be fine. Modded are differnt. My modded server, we had to custom rewrite some mods because they still used usernames rather than UUID. If you're playing on a mod pack, check with teh admins first to see if they are away of any issues. If so, set up a check/safeword or something so that when you change your name, they can move your data over (ask if they'll even do this and if they know how as it may require SQL knowledge and knowledge of how the mods store data.)

Comment: I've played on a few servers where changing my name reset my ingame balance and rank, but that's rare.

Answer (score 0):

in vanilla minecraft (neither plugins nor mods), you won't have any problems. in the case of plugins it depends on the server, so you might want to ask there. in the case of mods, some are known to store data in relation to your username (the first thing coming to my mind is extra utilities death inventory backup, although that's nothing you'd really care about on the average server. thaumcraft did the same with its research in 1.6, but i'm not sure whether that's still the case).

Answer (score 0):

You will not lose any of your single-player worlds, or any of the servers on your server list. Your progress **on** servers will vary from server to server.

Plain survival servers should be fine, as most things in Minecraft use your UUID now rather than name. Most modded servers should also be fine, as the majority of mods have moved to using the UUID system rather than name, though you may want to ask a server admin.

The main server type that you are likely to lose progress on is vanilla servers with command blocks. Mojang hasn't added UUID support for scoreboards, so you may lose points, kills, or whatever else is kept in scoreboards.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Most mods and plugins have been retrofitted to use the UUID system (unaffected by username). Some mods might still use the username system, in that case, yes. You will lose data.