# I can't join any servers on minecraft when I just changed my username

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I downloaded and re-downloaded,
logged back in and out multiple times,
I just changed my username,
I lost all of my data expect my skins,
someone help me please,
how do I get back my servers and worlds

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/230032/), some servers might cause you to lose your progress after changing your username (it might be dependent on the mods installed on that server, of which some don't use a player's UUID but their username).

It's probably best, based on [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/czbk1p/changed_name_lost_items_how_to_fix/eyxb5el?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), to

- ask the server admins to transfer your items from your old username to your current one, or
- download your old files and upload them again after having changed the ownership's UUID - which you can find [here](http://tools.glowingmines.eu/#load) - from your old to your new one.
- You can also authorize a friend on the server temporary ownership and ask them to gather your items and gift them to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you changed your username instead of switching/creating a new Minecraft account. Try the button on the bottom of the create new world menu (titled sync old worlds.) Otherwise, this is probably a glitch that you might want to report.